# SQL Server CE file location

Tags: wpf, sql-server-ce

I have a problem concerning the folder strcture of my project, which use SQL Server CE 3.5 (private deploy). The following pic show the folder structure that is fine (no error)

[image: Working version]
But I wold like to reorganize the folder as follows:
[image: Error version]

This throws an error, *"Unable to load the native components of SQL Server Compact corresponding to the ADO.NET provider of version 8080. Install the correct version of SQL Server Compact. Refer to KB article 974247 for..."*

So I tried to add the probing path in my config file:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <probing privatePath="dll"/>
  <dependentAssembly xmlns="">
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SqlServerCe" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.5.1.0-3.5.1.50" newVersion="3.5.1.50" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

but without success.  Is there any chance to force my code to check the required DLL in those folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible with the SQL Server Compact 3.5 provider, due to some flaws in the folder detection mechanism for private deployment.

Some improvements with private deployment in version 4.0 should enable this, but I assume you are using version 3.5 for a reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Well, sincerely I choosen 3.5 as test but if is bugged I will move to 4.0

Comment: Then move to 4.0 if you do not need replication support, a much better desktop db engine than 3.5 in a number of ways.

Comment: I succesfully moved my project to CE 4.0 but the folder problem still remain. I think there's no way to quit, are you agree?

Comment: I am a litlle surprised this does not work, but if it does not, I think there is no way to work around it - wonder if this ever actually worked? http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/06/sql-server-compact-private-deployment.html

Comment: It works, it was my fault as I tried to use OleDB connection with private deploy (which is not supported, right?)

Comment: Oledb connection is not supported on desktop at all